# How can ingesting a prion "infect" someone?

Tags: human-biology, prion, human-physiology

That's something that's been bugging me for a while...

Our gastrointestinal tract produces proteases that degrade proteins. Prions are proteins. Shouldn't they be broken by proteases?

Also, how can a prion pass the gastrointestinal barrier? Shouldn't the intestine be able to absorb aminoacids only (instead of full proteins)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prions are misfolded proteins with abnormal tertiary or quaternary structures. [That grants them resistance (to some extent, at least) to proteases (1)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24338008).

Also researchers believe that [prions are able to replicate (2)](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199609193351218), by changing the structure of other proteins.

Regarding the gastrointestinal barrier, that isn't exactly true. [It has been shown that small quantities of intact proteins do cross the gastrointestinal tract in animals and adult humans (3)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3060169), and that this is a physiologically normal process required for antigen sampling by subepithelial immune tissue in the gut

---

So, the resistance to the proteases and the ability to replicate in certain conditions might explain the odds of a prion crossing the gastrointestinal tract and infecting an individual.

---

**References:**

1. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24338008
2. http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM199609193351218
3. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3060169

Comment: I think explaining the replication process here is worth including for a more complete answer.